# AFNetworking and configuring HTTP_ACCEPT

Tags: afnetworking

The documentation for AFNetworking notes that you should create subclass of AFHTTPClient and use it as a singleton per web-service.

If I have 2 endpoints at www.example.com, one that allows for 'application/json' in HTTP_ACCEPT and another that needs text/html, what parameter would I configure in my singleton AFHTTPClient class so that it configures the correct HTTP_ACCEPT value?

Implementation details:

```
@interface MyAFHTTPClient : AFHTTPClient
+ (MyAFHTTPClient *)sharedClient;
@end

[[MyAFHTTPClient sharedClient] getPath:@"endPoint_json"
                                     parameters:nil 
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
}]
```

At a later time, I need to invoke the html endpoint:

```
[[MyAFHTTPClient sharedClient] getPath:@"endPoint_html"
                                     parameters:nil 
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
}]
```

It seems that both of these calls cause `"HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"application/json"` when the server receives the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPath:...` and all of those convenience methods construct a request with `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:`, and then pass that into `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:`, which is then enqueued into an operation queue.

If you need to do a one-off request for HTML or the like, do these steps manually rather than using the convenience method: create the request, set the `Accept` (HTTP_ACCEPT) is not an HTTP header) header to `text/html`, and then create and enqueue the operation.